# Proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem in the book of Peter Walters; An introduction to Ergodic Theory.

Page 39.

The second case when $m(X)=+\infty$.

After the sentence (The function $H_N$ ...) I couldn't understand many things.

Why is the set $E_{\alpha,\beta}$ contained in the union ?

Why is the $$\alpha m(C)\leq\int|f|dm$$

Why since $X$ is $\sigma -$ finite then $m(E_{\alpha,\beta})<+\infty$? 
[image][image][image]

Comment: We also need the definition of $h_N$. For your third question, write $E_{\alpha,\beta}$ as a non-decreasing sequence of set of finite measure $(C_k)$. The measure of $C_k$ is bounded independently of $k$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo like $F_N$ in the third image

Comment: What are the definitions of $f^*,f_*$?

Comment: @AlexR. Are they clear ? Now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $E_{\alpha,\beta}\subset \bigcup_{N=0}^{+\infty}\left\{H_N\gt 0\right\}$ follows from the fact that if $x\in E_{\alpha,\beta}$, then 
$$
\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^i\left(x\right)\gt \alpha
$$
which means that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(f-\alpha\right)\circ T^i\left(x\right)\gt 0
$$
and in particular, there should exists some $N$ such that $\left(f-\alpha\right)\circ T^N\left(x\right)\gt 0$ which implies that $\left(f-\alpha\mathbf 1_C\right)\circ T^N\left(x\right)\gt 0$ hence $H_N(x)\gt 0$.

The inequality obtained after an application of the maximal ergodic theorem reads 
$$
\alpha\cdot  m\left(C\cap \left\{x: H_N(x)\gt 0\right\}\right)\leqslant \int_{\left\{ H_N \gt 0\right\}}f\mathrm dm.
$$
The right hand side do not exceed $\int_{\left\{ H_N \gt 0\right\}}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm\leqslant\int_{X}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm $ hence 
$$
\alpha\cdot  m\left(C\cap \left\{x: H_N(x)\gt 0\right\}\right)\leqslant \int_{X}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm.
$$
Since the sequence of sets $\left(C\cap \left\{x: H_N(x)\gt 0\right\}\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ is non-decreasing and the union of these sets is $C$, we can take the limit as $N\to \infty$ to get 
$$
\alpha\cdot  m\left(C\right)\leqslant \int_{X}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm.
$$

To conclude, we use $\sigma$-finiteness of $E_{\alpha,\beta}$ to write this set as the non-decreasing union of a sequence $\left(C_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ of set of finite measure. Since for all $k$,
$$
 m\left(C_k\right)\leqslant \alpha^{-1}\int_{X}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm
$$
it follows that 
$$
 m\left(E_{\alpha,\beta}\right)\leqslant \alpha^{-1}\int_{X}\left\lvert f\right\rvert\mathrm dm.
$$