# Step in proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, proof-explanation, ergodic-theory

I have a question about the proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem in the book : An Introduction to Ergodic theory by *Peter Walters*.

At page 38 he tells us that :

> For reals $\alpha, \beta$ we define $E_{\alpha, \beta} := \{ x \in X \mid f_*(x) < \beta ~\text{and}~ f^*(x) > \alpha\}$.

> [...]

> From corollary 1.16.1 we get
> $$ \int_{E_{\alpha, \beta}} f dm = \int_{E_{\alpha, \beta} \cap B_\alpha} f dm \geq \alpha m(E_{\alpha, \beta} \cap B_\alpha) = \alpha m(E_{\alpha, \beta}). $$
> If we replace $f, \alpha, \beta$ by $-f, -\beta, -\alpha$, respectively, then since
> $(-f)^\ast = -f_\ast$ and $(-f)^\ast = -f_\ast$ we get
> $$ \int_{E_{\alpha, \beta}} f dm \leq \beta m(E_{\alpha, \beta}). $$

But basically if we do the substitution we get
$$ \int_{E_{-\beta, -\alpha}} f dm \leq \beta m(E_{-\beta, -\alpha}). $$
So my question is : how we can go from $E_{-\beta, -\alpha}$ to $E_{\alpha, \beta}$ ?

Comment: you can take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881826/proof-of-birkhoff-ergodic-theorem I asked a similar question almost 4 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
E_{-\beta,-\alpha}(-f) := \left\{ x \in X \mid (-f)_*(x) < -\alpha ~\text{and}~ (-f)^*(x) > -\beta\right\}\\
=\left\{ x \in X \mid -(f^*)(x) < -\alpha ~\text{and}~ -(f)_*(x) > -\beta\right\}\\
=\left\{ x \in X \mid  (f^*)(x) >\alpha ~\text{and}~  (f)_*(x) <\beta\right\}
=E_{\alpha,\beta}(f),
$$
where the second equality follows from your observations that $(-f)_*=-(f^*)$
and $(-f)^*=-(f_*)$.

Comment: you also answered me 4 years ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881826/proof-of-birkhoff-ergodic-theorem

Comment: @Neilhawking Wow, you have a very good memory!

Comment: bien sûr :) :) :)